# Importance of Calling SetState inside initState

Tags: flutter

Should `setState()` method be called inside `initState()` method of a `StatefullWidget`?

My understanding is that `initState()` method will automatically apply the state.

The code below does not work. The post object is evaluated as null.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    ItemService.getItemById(widget.postId).then((DocumentSnapshot doc){
        post = ItemService.getPostFromDocument(doc);
    });
  }
```

But the below works.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    ItemService.getItemById(widget.postId).then((DocumentSnapshot doc){
      setState((){
        post = ItemService.getPostFromDocument(doc);
      });
    });
  }
```

Some other cases, all works fine even without using `setState()` in the same class.

So when should I use `setState()` inside `initState()` method and when not to?

**Another Relevant Questions:**

When should I call `super.initState()` inside my `initState()`? Does it matter if I didn't call?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe your first example doesn't work because you don't call `super.initState()`. Did you try it?

Comment: Haven't tried.. But how super.initState() has an impact? I am trying to understand how it works. I doubt it because in the same class, other states work fine even without calling supers initState.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52295949/10269042

Comment: Already seen. It explains what is initState and does not explain my question.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `setState()` method notifies the framework that the internal state of the Stateful widget has changed. Calling this method is what triggers the widget to rebuild with the latest state values, so it is not necessary to call it inside the `initState()` lifecycle method since it is only called once when the widget is inserted into the widget tree (i.e. when the widget is initialized).

You can read more about the `setState()` method here: [setState method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

As for the `initState()` lifecycle method, whenever you override this method you **MUST** call `super.initState();` at the start or end of your method, otherwise, you'll encounter some problems with your widget. Problems like the widget not being inserted into the widget tree.

The only time you can use `setState()` inside `initState()` is within a callback function as you did in the second code snippet. It works because, by the time the callback is run, the widget has already been initialized and inserted into the widget tree and the internal state needs to be updated to trigger a rebuild.

Also, just take note that `setState()` will only work if the widget is mounted. For this reason, every widget has a `bool this.mounted` property which you can check in case you're not certain if the widget will still be mounted when `setState()` is called. Calling it when the widget is not mounted might crash your app. So I'd advice against calling `setState()` outside the widget class.

Answer (score 30):

You don't need to use `setState` within initState. In fact, it will not work if you do so.

The thing is, you are *not* calling `setState` within `initState` in your example.

What you do is calling `setState` on an asynchronous event. But since it's asynchronous, the `initState` method has already finished

Comment: Thanks. But its confusing.. Should I be wrapping all my async calls within the setState method inside initState? or should not use it at all? Your answer provides 2 different meaning. Can you please explain or post a simple example..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `setstate()` if you want to call an async method inside the `initstate()` but if it's not an async method then you'll face a trouble because you'd be trying to rebuild state of the widget even before it is built. Basically the answer is yes: you should call `setstate()` all the time you are to execute an asynchronous function inside `initstate()`. I strongly reccomend you search about lifecycle of widgets.