# How to solve - no items in the list showing initially, while using TextField for search until typed anything in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project, I am getting some value by API call. I call the function inside my **initState** function and then save the result in a list.

Then, I have added the one **TextField** to make the search in my list. The search is working properly but the problem is - **initially no items are shown in the list. If I type something or after typing I delete those text it's working**.

**Here's my code-**

Inside the class I have added the following variables-

```
  List<ModelAllNotes> _allNotes = List<ModelAllNotes>();
  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
  var items = List<ModelAllNotes>();
```

Inside the **initState** function I have called a function-

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      _getAllNotes();
      items.addAll(_allNotes);
    });
  }
```

Inside the **_getAllNotes()** function I have done the API calling part-

```
  void _getAllNotes() {
    Webservice().load(ModelAllNotes.allNotes).then( (allNotes) => {
      setState(()=>{
        _allNotes = allNotes

      })
     });
  }
```

**For filtering**, the list while searching I have created a function for that-

```
 void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    List<ModelAllNotes> dummySearchList = List<ModelAllNotes>();
    dummySearchList.addAll(_allNotes);
    if(query.isNotEmpty) {
      List<ModelAllNotes> dummyListData = List<ModelAllNotes>();
      dummySearchList.forEach((item) {
        if(item.title.contains(query)) {
          dummyListData.add(item);
        }
      });
      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(dummyListData);
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(_allNotes);
      });
    }

  }
```

Then inside the build function I have done the list showing part like below way-

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                filterSearchResults(value);
              },
              controller: editingController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Search",
                  hintText: "Search",
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
            ),
          ),

          Expanded (
            child: Container(
              child: new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                    return new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          child: Container(
                            child: showCard(index),
                          ),
                          onTap: (){
                            print('Card pressed');
                            Navigator.pushNamed(ctxt, '/DetailsNotes', arguments: items[index]).then((val)=>{_getAllNotes()});
                          },

                        ),
                      )

                    );

                  }
              ),

            ),
          )

        ],

      )
    );
```

After doing all these stuff it is showing the blank screen initially. When I type something in the search TextField it showing the list. So, I need a solution to show the list when the screen appears.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `setState` twice (one on `initState` and other on the fn you call `_getAllNotes`)

This post explains a little why you shouldn't 
 call it the way you're doing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53373017/4902078.

But I think the problem is that on your `initState` you call

```dart
_getAllNotes();
items.addAll(_allNotes);
```

And inside `_getAllNotes` you make a call to the server and in the `then` statement you update `_allNotes`. When the `than` content is called, the `items.addAll(_allNotes);` probably has already been run, and it adds an empty list. If you added your `items.addAll(_allNotes);` inside the `setState` inside the `_getAllNotes` maybe it would work.