# I've created my search_dart file but I keep getting this flutter error LateInitializationError: Field 'docsSnap' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-2

I am building a Flutter application and I have integrated Firebase. I'm trying to launch my homedart after the dart2 update but for some reason I cant just need some help I've attached the code below:

```
`class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  late Screen size;
  int _selectedIndex = -1;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  List<Property> recentList =  [];
  List<Property> topList =  [];
  var citiesList = ["Ahmedabad", "Mumbai", "Anand", "Delhi ", "Vadodara", "Chennai","Goa","Kolkata","Indore","Jaipur"];
  Image? image1;
  String? docRef;
  String? isLoggedIn;
  late DocumentSnapshot? docsSnap;

  void getUserDetails() async{
    isLoggedIn= await LocalStorage.sharedInstance.loadAuthStatus(Constants.isLoggedIn);
    docRef= await LocalStorage.sharedInstance.loadUserRef(Constants.userRef);
    print('docRef :'+ docRef!);
    if(docRef != "NULL"){
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('/User/'+docRef!).get().then((DocumentSnapshot docs) {
        print("Doc found");
        setState(() {
          docsSnap = docs;
        });
      });
    }else{
      setState((){docsSnap=null;});
      print("Doc Not Exist");
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    setState((){docsSnap=null;});
    getUserDetails();

    image1 = Image.asset("assets/drawer_design.png", gaplessPlayback: true);

    topList
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Omkar Lotus", propertyLocation:"Ahmedabad ", image:"feature_1.jpg", propertyPrice:"26000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Sandesh Heights", propertyLocation:"Baroda ", image:"feature_2.jpg", propertyPrice:"11500", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Sangath Heights", propertyLocation:"Pune ", image:"feature_3.jpg", propertyPrice:"19000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''));

    recentList
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Vishwas CityRise", propertyLocation:"Pune ", image:"hall_1.jpg", propertyPrice:"17500", propertyDesc: '', id: ''))
      ..add(Property(propertyName:"Gift City", propertyLocation:"Ahmedabad ", image:"hall_2.jpeg", propertyPrice:"13500000", propertyDesc: '', id: ''));
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    precacheImage(image1!.image, context);
  }`
```

I'm not sure what to do but now I've exhausted my options

Comment: Could you please provide the error as a screenshot or code snippet? Also, have you initialized and configured Firebase?

Comment: Remove `late` keyword before `DocumentSnapshot? docsSnap;`

Comment: Also don't call `setState()` inside `initState` https://stackoverflow.com/a/53373017/11218270

Comment: Use a `FutureBuilder` instead of `getUserDetails()`

Comment: Doing asynchronous operation in `initState()` is a bad practice

Comment: happy_san when i run the code with your changes i get a new error of Failed assertion: line 42 pos 16: 'path.isNotEmpty': is not true.