# Start an Alert by opening page with Flutter web

Tags: flutter, web, alert, flutter-web

**Final Code which solved it**

```
  @override
void initState() {
super.initState();

Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
  Alert(
    context: context,
    title: "JOJOJO",
    desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
  ).show();
});
}
```

I want to build an Flutter alert into my web app and when I open the website I want to pop it up immediately.
The alert is build with the rflutter_alert package.

Does somebody have a solution to open this alert automatically?

**Code of the Alert**

```
_onBasicAlertPressed(context) {
Alert(
  context: context,
  title: "JOJOJO",
  desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
).show();
}
```

**With the init State**

Apparently it doesn't work when I just put it into the init state.
However another function works with this way, the function that i want to activate for now only works by using onpressed in a button.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    Alert(
  context: context,
  title: "JOJOJO",
  desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
).show();
super.initState();
callSendData();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your method in the `initState()`

```
class StatefulWrapper extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _StatefulWrapperState createState() => _StatefulWrapperState();
}

class _StatefulWrapperState extends State<StatefulWrapper> {

 @override
  void initState() {
     Alert(
       context: context,
       title: "JOJOJO",
       desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
     ).show();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

[What is init state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295949/what-is-initstate-and-super-initstate-in-flutter/54050203#:%7E:text=Credit%20to%20%40Remi%2C%20initState(),this%20method%20is%20called%20once.)

Comment: Ok i tried this but it didn't worked out. I updated my question

Comment: Ok i got a Problem but it worked out now Solutino: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395081/unhandled-exception-inheritfromwidgetofexacttype-localizationsscope-or-inheri